# Lock using atomic operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, atomic

Yes, I'm aware of that the following question could be answered with "Use the lock keyword instead" or something similar. But since this is just for "fun", I don't care about those.

I've made a simple lock using atomic operations:

```
public class LowLock 
{
    volatile int locked = 0;

    public void Enter(Action action)
    {
        var s = new SpinWait();

        while (true)
        {
            var inLock = locked; // release-fence (read)

            // If CompareExchange equals 1, we won the race.
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locked, 1, inLock) == 1)
            {
                action();
                locked = 0; // acquire fence (write)
                break; // exit the while loop
            }
            else s.SpinOnce(); // lost the race. Spin and try again.
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm using the lock above in a simple for loop, that adds a string to a normal `List<string>`, with the purpose of making the `add` method thread-safe, when wrapped inside the `Enter` method from a `LowLock`.

The code looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = new List<int>();

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var cd = new CountdownEvent(10000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            low.Enter(() => numbers.Add(i));
            cd.Signal();
        });
    }

    cd.Wait();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Time = {0} | results = {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, numbers.Count);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Now the tricky part is that when the main thread hits the `Console.WriteLine` that prints time and number of elements in the list, the number of elements should be equal to the count given to the `CountdownEvent` (10000) - It works most of the time, but sometimes there's only 9983 elements in the list, other times 9993. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [`SpinLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx) structure as it appears to do exactly what you want.

---

That said, this all looks really dicey, but I'll have a stab at it.

You appear to be *trying* to use `0` to mean 'unlocked' and `1` to mean 'locked'.

In which case the line:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locked, 1, inLock) == 1)
```

isn't correct at all. It's just replacing the `locked` variable with the value of `1` (locked) if its current value is the same as the last time you read it via `inLock = locked` (and acquiring the lock if so). Worse, it is **entering the mutual exclusion section if the original value was `1` (locked), which is the exact opposite of what you want to be doing**.

You should actually be atomically checking that the lock has not been taken (original value == 0) and take it if you can  (new value == 1), by using `0` (unlocked) as both the `comparand` argument as well as the value to test the return value against:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locked, 1, 0) == 0)
```

Now even if you fixed this, we also need to be certain that the `List<T>.Add` method will 'see' an up to date internal-state of the list to perform the append correctly. I *think*  `Interlocked.CompareExchange` uses a full memory barrier, which should create this pleasant side-effect, but this does seem a little dangerous to rely on (I've never seen this documented anywhere).

I strongly recommend staying away from such low-lock patterns except in the most trivial (and *obviously* correct) of scenarios unless you are a genuine expert in low-lock programming. We mere mortals *will* get it wrong.

**EDIT**: Updated the compare value to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) If we forget about the `SpinLock` etc. for a moment (I'm just doing this for fun) - You're absolutely right, `(ref locked, 1, inLock) == 1` would evaluate true even if `locked` and `inLock` equals 1. Replacing it with `(ref locked, 1, 0) == 1` didn't fix the problem (still printing numbers under the actual count).

Comment: Ah, that did it! Can't believe I missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Interlocked.CompareExchange` returns the original value of the variable, so you want something like this:

```
public class LowLock
{
    int locked = 0;

    public void Enter( Action action )
    {
        var s = new SpinWait();

        while ( true )
        {
            // If CompareExchange equals 0, we won the race.
            if ( Interlocked.CompareExchange( ref locked, 1, 0 ) == 0 )
            {
                action();
                Interlocked.Exchange( ref locked, 0 );
                break; // exit the while loop
            }

            s.SpinOnce(); // lost the race. Spin and try again.
        }
    }
}
```

I've removed the volatile and used a full fence to reset the flag, because [volatile is hard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx)